# How to change predefined Abstract?

Tags: fonts, ieeetran, abstract

In the conference paper, the predefined abstract is small and italicized. I can change the size and the position of the Abstract but I can't find anywhere how to un-italicize it. Is there a way to do that?

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference]{IEEEtran}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\large ABSTRACT\\}
\title{Example}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locally modify the original definition. An original line commented.

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference]{IEEEtran}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\large ABSTRACT\\}
\title{Example}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
  \ifCLASSOPTIONconference% compsoc conference
%\def\abstract{\normalfont\@IEEEtweakunitybaselinestretch{1.15}\bfseries
\def\abstract{\itshape\@IEEEtweakunitybaselinestretch{1.15}\bfseries
    \if@twocolumn
      \@IEEEabskeysecsize\noindent\textit{\abstractname}---\relax
    \else
      \bgroup\par\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}\centering\vspace{-1.78ex}\@IEEEabskeysecsize\textbf{\abstractname}\par\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}\egroup\quotation\@IEEEabskeysecsize%
    \fi\@IEEEgobbleleadPARNLSP}
\makeatother


\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This is abstract.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used this but it made the whole abstract italicized. I deleted \itshape and \textit and it worked perfectly so thank you.

Comment: @Scarlet Oh, my misunderstanding. My abstract was upright, so I have changed it to an italicised one.

Comment: Well without your code I would've never figured it out on my own. After all I am new at this. So you helped me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Does anyone know how to bring the abstract text in the same line as the abstract title? @PrzemysławScherwentke

Answer (score 1):

You could also disarm `\textit` locally:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\large ABSTRACT\\}
\let\oldabstract\abstract
\renewcommand\abstract{%
  \begingroup
  \let\textit\relax
  \oldabstract
  \endgroup
  \bfseries
}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\endabstract{\vspace{1em}\par}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Example}
\author{Scarlet}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\lipsum[2-10]
\end{document}
```

(I put some space after the abstract, i.e. `\g@addto@macro\endabstract{\vspace{1em}\par}`. In my opinion it looks a little better.)

[image: output]